# pgfplots Plot moving down page with yrange

Tags: pgfplots

With the following:

events.dat

```
y mean lower upper
0 7.70234e-08 6.73448e-08 8.67019e-08
0.1 8.49244e-08 7.72264e-08 9.26225e-08
0.2 1.1735e-07 1.02559e-07 1.32141e-07
0.3 3.06841e-07 2.47066e-07 3.66616e-07
0.4 1.59601e-06 1.36706e-06 1.82496e-06
0.5 5.95445e-06 4.11006e-06 7.79884e-06
0.6 -5.19059e-06 -1.05236e-05 1.42373e-07
0.7 -6.53589e-05 -9.47471e-05 -3.59706e-05
0.8 -0.000211282 -0.000255298 -0.000167265
0.9 -0.00041731 -0.000518634 -0.000315985
1 -0.000812216 -0.000998166 -0.000626266
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \begin{axis}[
                    width=0.5\textwidth,
                    height=0.5\textwidth,
                    xlabel=X,
                    ylabel=Y,
                    title=This is a title,
                    ymin=-0.0003,
                    ymax=0.000012,
                ]
                \addplot[
                    red,
                    name path=max,
                ] table[
                    x=y,
                    y=upper,
                ] {events.dat};
                \addplot[
                    green,
                    name path=min,
                ] table[
                    x=y,
                    y=lower,
                ] {events.dat};
                \addplot[
                    blue,
                    opacity=0.1,
                ] fill between[of=min and max];
            \end{axis}
            \draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

With the `ymin` and `ymax` lines commented it is fine. Then with these in play, and with smaller and smaller values for `ymin`, for example, `-0.0006`, `-0.0005`, `-0.0004`, and -`0.0003`, the plot moves down the page, with `-0.0001` finally pushing it off the bottom of the page. Why? I want to have `<= -0.0001` and still have the plot on the page!

Furthermore, suggested by a comment if you draw the bounding box one can see the stretching:

[image: bounding box stretched]

Comment: Curious. If you add `\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);` at the end of the `tikzpicture` environment you'll see that the bounding box is obviously calculated wrongly. Why that happens though, I cannot say.

Comment: Seems like an issue with the `fill between` library: If you remove the last `addplot` which applies the `fill between` then the excess vertical spacing goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the actual box size is reported due to the following (after adding `clip=false` to the axis)

[image]

This is the vertical box saved but then since it is clipped it is placed at the baseline. You can add `restrict y to domain=-5e-4:0.1` to restrict this drawing and it would get better.

Probably the fill between doesn't yet respect the clipping but still thinks it has the full visible context. It might be a bug or a quirk. So another one for Christian Feuersänger.